# Azure Web Application Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, authentication

I am completely a novice about Asp.net and Azure platform. I created a simple web application in VS2013 and deployed it to Azure web application. When I try to open my url (xxx.azurewebsites.net) it shows me a login page that my local application does not consist.

I digged some info about it, but due my knowledge level of web development and Azure platform, I did not understand the problem. It seems Azure Active Directory should be used, but I am not certain about it.

My question is, is there a way to skip the login page? If not, how can I define credentials to my application to be accessed?

Thank you.

Comment: you probably included Azure AD auth in your app.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Visual Studio 2013 offers several authentication options (No Authentication, Individual User Accounts, [Organizational Accounts](https://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#orgauth) and Windows Authentication) for the Web Forms, MVC, and Web API templates.

[image]

According to your description, it seems that you select **Organizational Accounts** option for your application, which will configure the application to use Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) for authentication based on user accounts in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD, which includes Office 365) or Windows Server Active Directory. If you don’t want authentication for your application, please choose **No Authentication** option when you create the project.

Comment: any updates? are you selecting Organizational Accounts option?